# Time range panel not available in Grafana

Tags: time, grafana, dashboard

I am trying to customize the time range for some of the panels in my dashboard and from what I can see in SO and other places online, there should be a "Time range" panel available, but I cant find it.

What I do:

- Inside my dashboard, I add a new panel.
- Add a query to the new panel
- Choose Single Stat as visualization

.. and the get the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot of new panel]

neither of the 3 options on the left give me a option to customize the Time Range.

Anyone know what I do wrong? Or what I am missing?

When looking at the Grafana github page, I can see that the time range option initially was created for graphs - but even there I can't see it.

The datasource is elasticsearch, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user "beatrice" have written, the answer can be found in the Grafana Community. The "Time range" panel is among others now showing anymore in the newer versions.

The below screenshot fixes the question:

[image: Solution from Grafana Community]

Link to the page [here](https://community.grafana.com/t/time-range-missing/17718/9)